# I am creating a pubsub class in js , but i am having issue with the the class export import

Tags: javascript, node.js, publish-subscribe

I am creating a pubsub class for javascript . where 3 methods are there "publish, subscribe, unsubscribe". I wrote the logic for publish and subscribe but can figure out about the unsubscribe method.My pubsub js looks like this .

```
    class PubSub {
    constructor() {
        this.subscription = []
    }

    publish(namespace, payload) {
        console.log('publishing');
        if (!this.subscription[namespace]) return;
        this.subscription[namespace].forEach(callback => {
            callback(payload)
        })
    }

    subscribe(namespace, callback) {
        console.log('subscribing')
        if (!this.subscription[namespace]) {
            this.subscription[namespace] = [];
        }
        this.subscription[namespace].push(callback);
    }

    unsubscribe(namespace, callback) {
        if (!this.subscription[namespace]) return;
        this.subscription[namespace].splice(index, 1);
    }
}
module.exports = PubSub;
```

And my event publisher looks like this :-

```
const { PubSub } = require('./pubsub');
const pubsub = new PubSub();
exports.PublishEvent = () => {
    const data = {
        msg: "Bla bla data"
    };

    pubsub.publish(data);
}
```

and event subscriber looks like this

```
const { PubSub } = require("./pubsub");
const pubsub = new PubSub();
pubsub.subscribe("anEvent", data => {
    console.log(
        `"anEvent", was published with this data:"${data.message}"`
    )
})
```

By the meantime i am having issue

```
const pubsub = new PubSub();
               ^

TypeError: PubSub is not a constructor
```

can any one help me to solve this issue and make the code work . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an instance/object of PubSub class. Try this

```
import { PubSub } from 'pubsub-js';

// to publish
PubSub.publish("anEvent", {message = "hello world!"});

//to subscribe
PubSub.subscribe("anEvent", data => {
  console.log(
    `"anEvent", was published with this data:"${data.message}"`
  )}
);
```

Their documentation has got examples https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS#readme